# How/where to define fancybox defaults?

Tags: jquery, fancybox

Let's say this is my fancybox config:

```
   $(".fancybox").fancybox({
      'transitionIn':'fade',
      'transitionOut':'fade',
      'speedIn':150,
      'speedOut':150,
      'changeSpeed':150,
      'changeFade':150,
      'overlayOpacity':0.1,
      'overlayColor':'#000000',
      'padding':0,
      'margin':20,
      'titleShow':false,
      'centerOnScroll':true
   });
```

But, what I would like to do, is to somehow define the config as the fancybox default, so that consequently when I bind an element, I can only do this:

`$(".newElement").fancybox();`

And it will automatically have my config.

Comment: Why not just store your config object in a variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation here: http://fancybox.net/api

> You can pass options as key/value object to fancybox() function or modify them at the bottom of FancyBox JS file

Answer (score 20):

Fancybox has an internal set of defaults that can easily be overridden.

For Fancybox 1.3, use:

```
jQuery.extend(jQuery.fn.fancybox.defaults, {
  hideOnOverlayClick: false,  //
  overlayOpacity: 0.75,       // <-- just an example
  overlayColor: '#222'        //
});
```

For Fancybox 2.0, the ".fn" is dropped:

```
jQuery.extend(jQuery.fancybox.defaults, {
  type: 'ajax'  // <-- for example
});
```

The Fancybox javascript file needs to be loaded first, of course.

Answer (score 2):

You can use JQuery Extend to merge the contents of two or more objects together.

Here the config:

```
var fancyboxConfig = {
    'transitionIn':'fade',
    'transitionOut':'fade',
    'speedIn':150,
    'speedOut':150,
    'changeSpeed':150,
    'changeFade':150,
    'overlayOpacity':0.1,
    'overlayColor':'#000000',
    'padding':0,
    'margin':20,
    'titleShow':false,
    'centerOnScroll':true
};
```

Then you can use then directly:

```
$(".newElement").fancybox(fancyboxConfig);
```

or merge/override them:

```
$(".newElementNoEffect").fancybox(
    $.extend({}, fancyboxConfig, {
        openEffect: 'none',
        closeEffect: 'none',
    })
);
```

More Info: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/

Answer (score 1):

This is how I do it (according to [the latest (fancybox3) documentation](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/docs/#options)):

```
         $.fancybox.defaults.clickOutside = 'close'

         $.fancybox.defaults.slideShow = {
             autoStart : false,
             speed     : myGallerySlideshowSpeed
         }
```

And so on. That is, I dont really initiate anything, I just have my items tagged `data-fancybox="gallery"` and use the above code to set defaults.

Comment: Works perfectly with the latest version. Thanks!